playwright tests extremely slow (cpu load)
i am trying to end-to-end test a plattform. i want to use playwright, but i am struggling to make it performant.
this is my config:
export default defineConfig({
  testDir: './frontendTests',
  expect: {
    timeout: 600 * 1000,
  },

  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 2,
  workers: 1, //process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  reporter: 'html',
  use: {
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },

  projects: [
    { name: 'setup_auth', testMatch: /auth.setup\.ts/ },
    {
      name: 'setup_project',
      testMatch: /project.setup\.ts/,
      dependencies: ['setup_auth'],

      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        storageState: 'frontendTests/.auth/user.json',
        viewport: { height: 1000, width: 2000 },
      },
    },

    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        storageState: 'frontendTests/.auth/user.json',
        launchOptions: {
          args: [
            '--use-gl=desktop', // Use desktop OpenGL
            '--enable-webgl', // Enable WebGL
            '--ignore-gpu-blocklist', // Ignore GPU blocklist
          ],
        },
      },
      dependencies: ['setup_project'],
    },

  ],
  webServer: {
    timeout: 6000000,
    command: './run_local_docker.sh --forceAll',
    url: 'http://localhost:8910',
    reuseExistingServer: true,
  },
})


this is one test example just opens up a page and looks for a testid. running this in a desktop chrome browser, it fully loads in 11s. (it needs to load a lot of stuff like a 3d map etc... so the loading time is ok). running the test in playwright, it needs around 40s to get the same thing done.
const authFile = (user) => `frontendTests/.auth/${user}.json`

users.forEach((user) => {
  tenants.forEach((tenant) => {
    test(`visual testing for ${user} and ${tenant}`, async ({ page }) => {
      test.setTimeout(500000)

      // Load authentication cookies for the user
      const cookiePath = authFile(user)
      if (!fs.existsSync(cookiePath)) {
        throw new Error(`Cookie file not found for user ${user}`)
      }

      const { cookies } = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(cookiePath, 'utf-8'))
      await page.context().addCookies(cookies)

      const url = `${process.env.TESTING_URL}/_/${tenant}/portfolio/project/table`
      await page.goto(url)

      await expect(page.getByTestId('tableToggleStack')).toBeVisible()
    })
  })
})


how can i figure out why this takes so long and why this would eat up 100% cpu at the loading times? running this in parallel (  workers: >1) is even way worse.
any idea how i can go forward from here?
Thanks a lot!
EDIT: there is one more thing:
Chromium and firefox are agreatly different in speed. what is going on here? Is that expected?


It's a bit difficult to optimize for a site we can't see, but await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "commit"}) might be a bit faster. Can you share a [mcve]? Thanks. test.setTimeout(500000) is an wildly long test--8 minutes. I'd hate to have that in CI.
